# How to approach and solve this proof?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation, fractions

Let e, f, g, h be positive integers.

Let $\frac{e}{f}$ < $\frac{g}{h}$

Show that $\frac{e}{f}$ < $\frac{e+g}{f+h}$ < $\frac{g}{h}$ is possible.

I know that you can say EH < GF, but I don't know what else to do from here. If someone can show me step by step what to do, I think it'd be great for my understanding.

Comment: Just cross multiply in the inequality you’re trying to prove to get something that’s equivalent and easier to prove. The cross multiplication is valid because everything is positive.

Comment: Right, because from there I think I can prove the numerator for the middle portion, but what about the denominator? I think thats the biggest rock in my way.

Comment: I don't think you mean "possible". Of course it's possible. I think you want to shoe that it always holds.

Answer (score 4):

From $\frac{e}f<\frac{g}h$ we have $eh<fg$.

1. $\frac{e}f<\frac{e+g}{f+h}\iff ef+eh<ef+fg\iff eh<fg$
2. $\frac{e+g}{f+h}<\frac{g}h\iff eh+gh<fg+gh\iff eh<fg$

Here cross multiplication is valid since $e, f, g, h$ are positive.

Comment: OH so thats how you proof for the later half. Thank you so much. I was stumped on how to do the denominator.

Comment: Wait, but what do the last inequalities of 1 and 2 actually show? I know that it makes sense, but what does it mean in terms of the entirety of the statement as a whole?

Comment: It shows that from the fact that $eh<fg$ holds, we can prove that $\frac{e}{f}<\frac{e+g}{f+h}<\frac{g}{h}$ will hold as well since they are equivalent.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, we should use the cross multiplication approach.

$$\frac{e}{f}<\frac{g}{h}$$

Therfore
$$eh<gf \tag{1}$$

Now lets deal with the first part of the inequality, namely
\begin{align*}
\frac{e}{f}&<\frac{e+g}{f+h}\\
e(f+h)&<f(e+g)\\
ef+eh&<fe+fg \tag{substracting $fe$}\\
eh&<fg .
\end{align*}
Which is actually true for all positive integers $(1)$. Doing the same process with the second part

\begin{align*}
\frac{e+g}{f+h}&<\frac{g}{h}\\
(e+g)h&<g(f+h)\\
he+hg&<g f+gh\tag{substracting $gh$}\\he&<gf
\end{align*}
Which is again true for all positive integers. Hence the statement holds for all cases

$\square$